# Here Maps Android App

Tags: android, here-api

Is it possible to start the Android Here app with "activity starter" like Waze or Google Maps?

Examples:

Google Maps Navigator:

> Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
>   DataUri: google.navigation:q=*[address to search]*&mode=*[walking / transit]*

Waze:

> Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
>   DataUri: waze://?q=*[address to search]*&navigate=yes

Answer (score 10):

I started HERE app as follows:

```
String url = "geo:" + lat + "," + lng;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse(url));
intent.setPackage("com.here.app.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

But I have not found any documentation about the intent. But Actually it works.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @Ostermann works perfectly fine but it will just pinpoint the final location on the map. If you want to automatically start the navigation mode (i.e. computes the available paths) you can use

```
String url = "google.navigation:q=" + lat + "," + lng;
```

I've checked and it works just fine.

Comment: This is more of a comment to a previous answer than an actual answer.

Comment: @Ondkloss you are right, but since I do not have 50 reputation I could not comment on the previous answer. Do you think I should delete my answer/comment?

Answer (score 0):

don't provide an App but a SDK, it might be possible to launch an activity with the HERE maps provided if the customer implements an App with the required manifest configuration and intent.